# NSURLConnection offline web page with image(s)

Tags: iphone, caching, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, html

I'm developping an app that download the content of a web page on the iPhone then store it so the user would be able to access it offline.

I'm using NSURLConnection to download the page, [as is the doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). But it downloads only the HTML code without extra content like images.

Even if images are not in a NSData structure, I would like have at least some references or some delegate method call.
An idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse the HTML code and download all referenced files yourself (and then modify the HTML to use relative URLs if it doesn't already). This is not a trivial problem. You might want to look at the source of Unix tools like wget to get an idea of how they do it. I believe libxml2 can parse HTML so that should probably be the library you want to look into.

Comment: For parsing HTML, I found a very good api called ElementParser.
Take a look at http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/ !